# How do I display the MySQL data in Angular

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I've been trying to learn some SQL for my covid-19 timepass and I managed to make data and all but I'm now stuck with this, I'm lost on how to repeat with angular the table that I got from my SQL DB in the TABLE BELOW!, I looked at W3School and couple other websites but I didn't get it.

PHP

```
if($connectServer->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed :".$connectServer->connection_error);
}

$result = $connectServer->query("SELECT * FROM Users");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"ID":"'  . $rs["userID"] . '",';
$outp .= '"First Name":"'  . $rs["FName"] . '",';
$outp .= '"Last Name":"'  . $rs["FName"] . '",';
$outp .= '"City":"'   . $rs["City"]        . '",';
$outp .= '"Email":"'. $rs["Email"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"names":['.$outp.']}';

echo($outp);?>
```

HTML

```
<table ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in names">
        <td>{{a.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{a.First Name}}</td>
        <td>{{a.LName}}</td>
        <td>{{a.City}}</td>
        <td>{{a.Email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("php/fetchDATA.php")
      .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
    });
</script>
```

fetchDATA.PHP

> {"names":[{"ID":"32","First Name":"ValueFName","Last Name":"ValueFName","City":"ValueCity","Email":"ValueEmail"},{"ID":"33","First Name":"ValueFName","Last Name":"ValueFName","City":"ValueCity","Email":"ValueEmail"},{"ID":"34","First Name":"ValueFName","Last Name":"ValueFName","City":"ValueCity","Email":"ValueEmail"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in each of your code like variable `{{a.First Name}}` having space and `{{a.LName}}` is not defined anywhere.

So you must change the variable declaration in php for the code to work.

Further the response you are expecting must have the variable records but the php you have defined does not have any such variable. Thus I will suggest you to read PHP and Angular tutorial again before asking the question.